Proving $\sum\limits_{i=0}^k\frac{(k+1)!}{i!(k+1-i)!}S_i=(n+1)^{k+1}-1$ given $S_k=\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni^k$
$S_k = 1^k + 2^k + 3^k + \ldots + n^k$. Prove that
$(k + 1)S_k + \frac{(k + 1)k}{2} S_{k-1} + \frac{(k + 1)k(k - 1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} S_{k-2} + \ldots + (k + 1)S_1 + S_0 = (n + 1)^{k + 1}-1 $.
I was trying some sort of combinatorial arguement the term on rhs represents total number of possible maps from A to B
where $|A|=  k+1  ,|B|= n+1 and A = ({1,2,...k+1}) ,B = ({1,2 ,..n+1 })$
we can think of $S_k$ as total number of maps from A to C where $|C| = n$ and $f(i)\leq f(k+1)$ $\forall i < k+1$

Induction on $n$ works well too, esp alongside Adam's hint,

Fix $k.$ Let $S_k$ be defined as in the question. We carry out (weak) induction on $n.$
Let $P(n)$ be the statement to be proved, that is,
$$(n + 1)^{k + 1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}S_i + 1 \tag{P(n)}\label{eq1} $$

Basis case: $n=1.$ Then $S_r=1$ for all $r.$ By Binomial theorem,
$$ (1+1)^{k+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}1^i = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}S_i + \binom{k+1}{k+1}S_{k+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}S_i + 1,$$
and so $P(1)$ is true.

Inductive step: Suppose $P(n-1)$ be true, that is,
$$ n^{k + 1} = 1+ \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}\left( 1^i + 2^i + \ldots + (n-1)^i \right) \tag{P(n-1)}\label{eq2} $$
Then by the Binomial theorem,
$$ (1+n)^{k + 1} = n^{k+1} + \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}n^i \tag{3}\label{eq3} $$
and by assumption that $\eqref{eq2}$ is true, (the right-hand side of \eqref{eq3}) is equal to
$$ 1+ \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}\left( 1^i + 2^i + \ldots + (n-1)^i \right) + \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}n^i $$
$$ = 1+ \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}\left( 1^i + 2^i + \ldots + (n-1)^i + n^i \right)$$
$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}S_i + 1, $$
and so $\eqref{eq1}$ is true, proving the inductive step.

I can give a combinatorial argument which proves your equation.
I will think of $(n+1)^{k+1}$ as representing lists of length $k+1$, where each entry is chosen from $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$. Then, $(n+1)^{k+1}-1$ will represent all such lists, except for the list of all zeroes.
Then, the term $\frac{(k+1)!}{i!\cdot (k+1-i)!}\cdot S_i$ will represent the number of lists which have $k+1-i$ maximal elements. Indeed, we can choose the locations of the $k+1-i$ maximum elements in $\frac{(k+1)!}{i!\cdot (k+1-i)!}$ ways. Suppose that the maximum of the list is $m$. Then there are still $i$ non-maximal elements of the list to fill, each of which must be chosen from $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$. Therefore, there are $m^i$ ways to fill the rest of the list. Summing over all $m$, the number of ways to fill the list is $\sum_{m=1}^{n}m^i=S_i$. Note that we start from $m=1$, because we excluded the list of all zeroes, so the maximum element must be at least $1$.
Since the number of maximal elements, $k+1-i$, is between $1$ and $k+1$, it follows that we must sum $\frac{(k+1)!}{i!\cdot (k+1-i)!}\cdot S_i$ from $i=0$ to $k$. This proves your equation.
